# elasticsearch: Get all documents that are children or grandchildren to the parent

Tags: elasticsearch, inner-join, parent-child

I am trying to search function that allows me to get all documents related to the parent showed appear.

eg:
Parent -> child -> grandchild -> grand-grandchild

If child is searched then the resultant documents that should appear are : child, grandchild and grand-grandchild.

If grandchild is searched then the resultant documents that should appear are : grandchild and grand-grandchild.

I have only found a way to find and display the child and the parent, however displaying the grandchild, child and parent is where i am stuck.

This is code to that searches for the child

```
get /mls/_search
{
    "query": {
        "parent_id": {
            "type": "child",
            "id": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

however it dose now show the grandchild as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `has_child` query to get all documents related to parent. The query first finds all documents that have child type document, then finds all documents related to grandchild and grand-grandchild. Don't forget to replace the query according to your needs in your mapping!

```
GET /mls/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "child",
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "grandchild",
          "query": {
            "has_child": {
              "type": "grand-grandchild"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```